# Async/await axios calls with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, async-await, axios

I'm having a little trouble setting one of my this. values within my Vue.js application. I believe I'm either not understanding async axios calls correctly, or how async works within Vue.js.

I have the following three methods:

```
updateAvailability(availability) {
    if (availability == true) {
        this.showYourDetails();
    } else {
        this.showBookingDetails();
    }
},
checkAvailability: async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const availability = await this.handleAvailabilityRequest(event);
    this.loading = true;
    console.log(availability); //This evaluates to undefined
    const availabilityUpdate = await this.updateAvailability(availability);
    this.loading = false;
},
handleAvailabilityRequest: async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let valid = this.validateFieldsForAvailabilityRequest(); //Ignore this for this particular question, assume valid is always true

    if (valid) { // This is true
        let config = {
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": this.csrfToken,
                "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        }

        let formData = new FormData();
        let reservationTime = this.reservationHourSelected + ':' + this.reservationMinuteSelected;

        formData.set('type', 'availability_request');
        formData.set('session_name', this.sessionName);
        formData.set('reservation_party_size', this.reservationPartySize);
        formData.set('reservation_date', this.reservationDate);
        formData.set('reservation_time', reservationTime);

        await axios.post('{{ request_absolute_uri }}', formData, config).then(function(response) {
            this.availabilityMessage = response.data.message;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            this.availabilityMessage = false;
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    return this.availabilityMessage;
}
```

My `response.data.message` is being passed back from my framework as True/true but it seems I'm not returning anything from the `await this.handleAvailabilityRequest()` function? The post definitely hits the server as logging shows everything I want - then returns back message = true in json response context.

So, I guess ... help! Completely dumbfounded as to why this isn't working other than it being an issue with waiting for the promise...

Comment: You should be using an arrow function here, otherwise you won't get the correct context.

Comment: Vivick is right, or add `.bind(this)` at the end of your error callback function.

Comment: since you are updating "this" availabilityMessage, I don't see a point in returning it in the request. Instead check this.availabilityMessage in the further calls down from there instead of availability.

Comment: You're also mixing async await with a standard promise. This can cause problems I've found. Either use one or the other. I prefer async/await for these situations, but i have also found times where i have to use a Promise.all on awaited calls.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
await axios.post('{{ request_absolute_uri }}', formData, config).then(function(response){
  this.availabilityMessage = response.data.message;
}).catch(function (error) {
  this.availabilityMessage = false;
  console.log(error);
});
```

Because you're using a full-fledged `function`, your `this` inside the `.then` does not refer to the instantiated object. Use an arrow function instead so that the `this` is inherited from the outer scope:

```
await axios.post('{{ request_absolute_uri }}', formData, config)
.then((response) => {
  this.availabilityMessage = response.data.message;
}).catch((error) => {
  this.availabilityMessage = false;
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. With a few modifications the outer scope is now changing. Just out of interest, why does this work?

Comment: With standard functions, `this` inside of any function is the *calling context* of that function - with your original code, that was the `Promise` returned by `.post`. With arrow functions, the `this` is always *inherited* from the outer scope, rather than depending on the calling context of the arrow function.

Comment: If you must use function() you can always bind the parent context (this) with bind. `function() {}.bind(this)`

Comment: You can also use the good ol’ `let vm = this` (or `var` if you need to go extreme)  at the very beginning of the method and use it in place of `this`.

Comment: if using Then , there's still need of using await ?

Comment: @Muhammad There's no *need* for it, but `await` in combination could result in the desired control flow. (The alternative would be to nest everything that follows in another `.then`)

Answer (score 24):

Why use promises pattern if you are using async await. This removes the use of callbacks and `this` binding being lost

You can do it like this

```
handleAvailabilityRequest: async function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    ...

  try{
   let response =  await axios.post('{{ request_absolute_uri }}', formData, config)
      this.availabilityMessage = response.data.message;
  }catch(error) {
      this.availabilityMessage = false;
      console.log(error);
    };
  }
  return this.availabilityMessage;
}
```

You can use `try/catch` block for handling errors when using `async/await`

Comment: "Why use promises if you are using async await" — Because an `async` function returns a promise and `await` can only wait for a function that returns a promise.

Comment: axios does return a promise

Comment: @Quentin we can await on that promise being resolved and return the `response`

Comment: "finally" is a great way to clean up after a try catch. I use it all the time

Comment: This is a better answer IMHO. async/await is a game changer. Avoiding those chained functions for promises defintely makes this cleaner.